# Use generic spark estimators in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, apache-spark

I want to be able to easily replace one Spark Estimator with another.
I've created method that uses generic estimator:

```
def evaluatePrecisionForUser(estimator:Estimator[Model[_]]): Double ={
...
val model = estimator.fit(trainingData)
...
}
```

Here's one of the classes that returns generic estimator that should be passed into above-mentioned method:

```
object RandomForestEstimatorBuilder {
    def build(): Estimator[Model[_]] ={
    ...
    val pipeline = new Pipeline()
    ...
    pipeline
  }
```

The last line gives this error:

> Error: type mismatch;  found   : org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline 
>   required: org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator[org.apache.spark.ml.Model[*]]
>   Note: org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel <:
>   org.apache.spark.ml.Model[*] (and org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline <:
>   org.apache.spark.ml.Estimator[org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel]), but
>   class Estimator is invariant in type M. You may wish to define M as +M
>   instead. (SLS 4.5)
>       pipeline

How that can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to have nothing to do with your higher-kinded type.

Your problem is that `RandomForestEstimatorBuilder` declares that it will return an `Estimator[Model[_]]`, but you are returning a `Pipeline` instead. You need to return an instance of `Estimator[Model[_]]` to match the declaration. This is a Scala issue--not Spark--and it's independent of the `evaluatePrecisionForUser` function you want to use later.